# symbol FT_Library_SetLcdFilter in libfontmanager.so not found error: Openjdk JRE

Tags: java, java-8, solaris, solaris-10

I've compiled openjdk from https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/ after 01/21 security patch update and when i integrated the JRE and given build with my project in Solaris, am getting the error like symbol FT_Library_SetLcdFilter in libfontmanager.so not found. Previous openjdk binaries seems to be working fine. Anyone has any idea?

Openjdk built in Solaris 10 for 64-bit version. Checked the sysmbol using ldd:

```
/usr/ccs/bin/nm -gD libfontmanager.so | grep FT_Library_SetLcdFilter
[45]    |                   0|                   0|FUNC |GLOB |0    |UNDEF  |FT_Library_SetLcdFilter
```

Error:

```
 [ia] No VM Pack files exist in this directory
       [ia] ChooseBundledVMs:  VMPack (Oracle JRE 1.7.0_60 Mac) not recognized
       [ia] BuildInstaller: Asked to load /bstorage/docusp/RXrs/build/RXrs.iap_xml
       [ia] Copying /bstorage/
docusp/RXrs/build/RXrsBuild.iap_xml. Using copy for build.
       [ia] Original project unchanged
       [ia] Unable to invoke the method:
       [ia]     Exec.setCommandLineArgs()
       [ia]     Some installer configuration information may be lost
       [ia] java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.c(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGl5.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGl5.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGl5.c(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGl5.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at InstallAnywhere.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at InstallAnywhere.main(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       [ia]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       [ia]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       [ia]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       [ia]     at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(DashoA10*..)
       [ia] Unable to invoke the method:
       [ia]     Exec.setStdoutVar()
       [ia]     Some installer configuration information may be lost
       [ia] java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.c(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGl5.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGl5.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGl5.c(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGl5.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at InstallAnywhere.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at InstallAnywhere.main(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       [ia]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       [ia]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       [ia]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       [ia]     at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(DashoA10*..)
       [ia] Unable to invoke the method:
       [ia]     Exec.setStderrVar()
       [ia]     Some installer configuration information may be lost
       [ia] java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.c(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGl5.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGl5.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGl5.c(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGl5.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at InstallAnywhere.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at InstallAnywhere.main(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       [ia]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       [ia]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       [ia]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       [ia]     at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(DashoA10*..)
       [ia] Unable to invoke the method:
       [ia]     Exec.setExitCodeVar()
       [ia]     Some installer configuration information may be lost
       [ia] java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.c(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGgn.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGl5.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGl5.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGl5.c(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at ZeroGl5.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at InstallAnywhere.a(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at InstallAnywhere.main(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       [ia]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       [ia]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       [ia]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
       [ia]     at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(DashoA10*..)
       [ia]     at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(DashoA10*..)
       [ia] IAResourceBundle: create resource bundle: de
       [ia] IAResourceBundle: create resource bundle: fr
       [ia] IAResourceBundle: create resource bundle: ja
       [ia] This project leverages AWT support, which is no longer supported. AWT will be replaced with Swing support.
       [ia] This project accepts VMs prior to 1.4, which are no longer supported. The project will be updated to require Java 1.4 or newer.
       [ia] ld.so.1: java: fatal: relocation error: file /common/java/jdk1.8.0_0221/jre/lib/amd64/libfontmanager.so: symbol FT_Library_SetLcdFilter: referenced symbol not found
       [ia] Result: 9
```

Comment: What are your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH_64` environment variables set to?

Answer (score 0):

That function should be found in the libfreetype.so library, version 2.3.0 (released 2007) or later.